# Signed capabilities build failures Xcode 12

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to create an archive in Xcode 12.

App connect is setup with me setup as a developer.

However, I keep getting the following messages when trying to build

> Personal development teams, including "XXXXX", do not support the Associated Domains capability.

and

> No profiles for 'com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx' were found
> Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.xxxxx.xxxxxx'.

I am new to iOS development and wanted to understand what could be causing the issue?

Comment: Did you purchase a Developer Membership?

Comment: We have a company app connect account where i have been setup as a developer and app manager so have two different email addresses for each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the development certificate and profile your company uses

These can be obtained from developer.apple.com under certificates and profiles

Xcode in some cases can do that for you should you provision your account through Preferences > Accounts

[image: hit the + button on the bottom left side]

Next step:

Validate the bundle id is the same as what you generated the profile for

such as a profile created using an identifier com.example.code needs a profile generated with appId com.example.code or a wild card profile.

Also when you import the developer certificate you will need the private key or you can create a new one as a team member but you profiles will need updating to append the newly generated cert

Now select project in the navigator and goto signing and capabilities, your newly imported profile and team should be available to select here, you can go to project settings for more advanced settings

[image]

Once all the above is done and you've selected Any iOS Device in the deployment target, hit the archive, it should do the trick